# A d3.select... equivalent to jQuery.children()

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm using d3 to append some elements on enter() and then update them later. However, the next time i try to select those elements the selection is much larger than the original. This is because the original selection elements now have children that are the same type e.g.; `<g>`, `<svg>`. I expected selectAll() to only work at the first decedent level like jQuery.children() is there an equivalent in d3? If not whats the most efficient way to shim that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no equivalent to `jQuery.children()`. This is usually handled by assigning a distinguishing class to the elements you want to select together, e.g. something like this.

```
svg.selectAll("g").data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", "parent")
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", "child");

svg.selectAll("g"); // all g elements
svg.selectAll("g.parent"); // only parents
svg.selectAll("g.child"); // only children
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using that method to mark the nodes i was looking for. As far performance, how does performing another select compare to something like d3.select(_.filter(svg.parent().node().children, function (el) { return el.nodeName == 'g';}))? in my situation I can have 10k + nodes in the DOM so I'm a little selection paranoid...

Comment: D3 uses the usual DOM selectors, so there shouldn't be too much overhead. In your case it might be better to specify the nodes to be selected explicitly, but switching between the two methods and profiling them shouldn't be too onerous.

Comment: What if we want to access children of `this`? Would `d3.select(this.some_class)` work?

Comment: Just add another `.select()` -- `d3.select(this).select(child)`.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a much better way to do it:

```
var parent = d3.selectAll(".myParentClass");
parent.each(function(d,i) {            
   var children = d3.selectAll(this.childNodes);
   console.log(children);
});
```

This way you don't need to unnecessarily add classes to what could be 100's of (or even more) child nodes.

Comment: Simple and working as expected, this is just as valid as the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also select children just with a CSS selector. Here what's I'm doing to select child from index:

```
d3.select(`#${parentId} > *:nth-child(${index + 1})`)
```

so I suppose this works:

```
d3.selectAll(`#${parentId} > *`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but at least in `d3` version 4, `selection.selectAll()` can take a function whose result is an array that contains the new elements to select based on the selected element in the previous selection:

```
var parent = d3.selectAll(".myParentClass");
var children = parent
    //Convert selection to selection representing the children
    .selectAll(function() { return this.childNodes; })
    //Apply filter to children
    .filter('g')
    ;
```

The primary benefit of this approach compared to the previous answers are that the `selection.data()` function will still work correctly.  The previously proposed methods, which assign results from a new, separate `d3.select()` call, do not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Like says Lars, there is no equivalent to 'children()' method in D3, but here left a little extension to d3.selection prototype i wrote. I hope must help you (so late).

```
d3.selection.prototype.children = function(d){
    var that = this.node();
    return this
        .selectAll(d)
        .filter(function(){ return that == this.parentNode; });
};
```