# d3 can't edit children css

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new using d3 but it is kind of making me crazy with something that seems so simple, basically I'm using the partition graph from d3, my idea is that when I click an element I will change it fill color to red, that's not a problem, pretty easy, however I want to also change all of its descendants fill color to red. I can access the children data and children of children data and would only need a recursive function to change the color, however what I cannot seem to access is the rect element associated with each child. I've tried the d3.select(child).style("fill", "red") function but it does not work, I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong but can someone point me in the right direction?

I have this locally but I am basically using this same example (I added jquery to my solution) http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html

In there, using firebug I set a breakpoint in partition.html on line 84. To hit that breakpoint I just click on a blue box in the graph and from there what I want is to be able to select the rect or the g elements associated to the one I clicked.

Again, I now I can do d.children[0] to get the data for the first child, but I do not know from there how to access/edit it css to change the color of it's fill.

Any help will be appreciated, also, I know I might not have given the best explanation, I'll gladly answer any question or try to clarify any confusion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think this has been asked before. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19956785/2670182)

Comment: I'm not sure it is the same thing, basically that gives me all child nodes, however I don't see a way to select the child elements of a given "g" element. since the structure of d3 is more "linear" than anything else. Or maybe I'm understanding that answer wrong, I'll continue to research.

Comment: Take a look at the structure of the selection object in devtools  - or whatever you are using - to help you think about it. And notice how the data is bound to the nodes and how the nodes are referenced by the selection structure.  You won't see any reference to the child nodes given to the parent node by d3. The DOM already has that with [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes). D3 is not about connecting nodes together, it's about capturing them in a selection structure based on data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Partition Layout

Like all of the d3 layouts I've worked with so far, the partition layout is all about data - not DOM elements.  Unfortunately, also like all of the layouts I've worked with so far, the documentation starts off on the wrong foot by stating the exact opposite...

> The partition layout produces adjacency diagrams: a space-filling variant of a node-link tree diagram. Rather than drawing a link between parent and child in the hierarchy, nodes are drawn as solid areas (either arcs or rectangles), and their placement relative to other nodes reveals their position in the hierarchy. The size of the nodes encodes a quantitative dimension that would be difficult to show in a node-link diagram.

It does no such thing :)
The only reference you will find to the partition object in the [example you linked](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html) is in the data method of the container selection.

```
[59]  var g = vis.selectAll("g")
[60]      .data(partition.nodes(root))
```

What the layout really does is...

> The partition layout produces ***a data structure and methods that support the generation of*** adjacency diagrams: a space-filling variant of a node-link tree diagram. Rather than drawing a link between parent and child in the hierarchy, nodes ,***<del>are</del>*** ***can be*** drawn as solid areas (either arcs or rectangles), ***<del>and</del>*** ***with*** their placement relative to other nodes ***<del>reveals</del>*** ***revealing*** their position in the hierarchy. The size of the nodes encodes a quantitative dimension that would be difficult to show in a node-link diagram.

You can then use d3 to generate a DOM structure for the tree, using that data structure.

My point is (*inter alia*) that there is no node structure - as in references between nodes - created by the layout.  That is up to you.

The object returned by `partition.nodes(root)` is just a flat array of js `object` types, with no references to any DOM elements.  But, it *does* have a rich set of state that gives you all of the positioning information you will need to build the DOM structure.

### Selecting child nodes

If you study the rendered structure, you will notice that all of the nodes are in the DOM structure at any given time; only their size and positioning are adjusted to suit the visualisation.  You will also notice that there is a strict spatial relationship between children and parents: any node to the right of a particular node who's vertical position is within the height of the said node, are it's children.  Further more, if you look at the structure of the data that is bound to each node, you will see these members: `x` `y` `dx` `dy`.  These are the normalised spatial characteristics of the node, so, given this state from your selected node, you can filter all of the nodes in the DOM structure to return a node list of the child nodes.

There are more than one ways to achieve this with d3, but one way is to use the `selection.classed` method...

```
    function hover(dActive){
        var x0 = dActive.x, y0 = dActive.y,
            x1 = x0 + dActive.dx, y1 = dActive.dy;
        g.classed("highlighted", function(d){
            return (d.y > y0) && (d.x >= x0) && (d.x < x1)
        })
    }
```

Here is a modified version of the example, with child highlighting on hover, using the above strategy...

```js
    var w = 600, //1120,
        h = 200, //600,
        x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]);

    var vis = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .style("width", w + "px")
        .style("height", h + "px")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

    d3.json("https://rawgit.com/cool-Blue/SO-Questions/master/partition/flare.json", function(root) {
        var g = vis.selectAll("g")
            .data(partition.nodes(root))
            .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")"; })
            .on("click", click)
            .on("mouseover", hover)
            .on("mouseout", function(){g.classed("highlighted", false)});

        var kx = w / root.dx,
            ky = h / 1;

        g.append("svg:rect")
            .attr("width", root.dy * kx)
            .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dx * ky; })
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                return d.children ? "parent" : "child";
            });

        g.append("svg:text")
            .attr("transform", transform)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.dx * ky > 12 ? 1 : 0; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; })

        d3.select(window)
            .on("click", function() { click(root); })

        function click(d) {
            if(!d.children) return;

            kx = (d.y ? w - 40 : w) / (1 - d.y);
            ky = h / d.dx;
            x.domain([d.y, 1]).range([d.y ? 40 : 0, w]);
            y.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);

            var t = g.transition()
                .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")"; });

            t.select("rect")
                .attr("width", d.dy * kx)
                .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dx * ky; });

            t.select("text")
                .attr("transform", transform)
                .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.dx * ky > 12 ? 1 : 0; });

            d3.event.stopPropagation();
        }

        function hover(dActive){
            var x0 = dActive.x, y0 = dActive.y,
                x1 = x0 + dActive.dx, y1 = dActive.dy;
            g.classed("highlighted", function(d){
                return (d.y > y0) && (d.x >= x0) && (d.x < x1)
            })
        }

        function transform(d) {
            return "translate(8," + d.dx * ky / 2 + ")";
        }
    });
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
        .chart {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 0;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        rect {
            stroke: #eee;
            fill: #aaa;
            fill-opacity: .3;
        }

        rect.parent {
            cursor: pointer;
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        text {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .highlighted rect {
            /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
            fill-opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did accept this as an answer because it does work, however what I ended up using is a bit different, since my json data includes ids I went and added the id to every single one of the rect elements (I'm using the partition graph, adding the id to the g elements was possible too), and from there I used jquery paired with the data d3 was giving back for the clicked element.

Comment: @apachecoq Yep, there are many ways and that's already two of them. The reason I focused on that way was because it exploits the abstract characteristics of the tree itself _using existing state_and also because it sort of explains that principle behind the tree (explaining to myself as much as anything). The good thing about your method which is shared by mine is that they are both soft references which won't cause potential memory leaks.